# Probability and Laplace/Fourier transforms to solve limits/integrals from calculus.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, limits, reference-request

I've seen in some answers in [Brilliant.org](http://brilliant.org/) to some very complicated limits and integrals that uses probabilistic arguments (Let $X$ be a random variable from $[0,1]$... [some examples are in those answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075772/probabilistic-arguments-in-calculus), [see also this for an example that has to do with evaluation of limit of a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk/493480#493480)) or some uses Laplace transforms or even Fourier series (Example see some answers by user [Tunk-Fey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/123277/tunk-fey): [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821710/int-0-infty-frac1-cos-tt-e-tdt/821805#821805), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499651/complex-integral-with-exponential/693983#693983) ). I would like to ask about a book that discusses those techniques, i.e. where to learn them?

$\bullet$ Edit: There's no problem if those techniques can only be learned from a particular section of one book or more (or even just a paper, as long as it is accessible to an upper-undergrad.).

Thanks in advance, that would really help me unlock my box of tools.

Comment: The Laplace transform and Fourier series will be discussed in pretty much any differential equations textbook.

Comment: I guess "Inside Interesting Integrals: A Collection of Sneaky Tricks, Sly Substitutions, and Numerous Other Stupendously Clever, Awesomely Wicked, " and Irresistible Integrals: Symbolics, Analysis and Experiments in the Evaluation of Integrals will be a good place to start searching

Comment: @Ahmed I have both books, but none contains a treatment of probabilistic methods. However Nahin's book contains a small discussion of Fourier series and how they can be used to determine the value of an integral using one example.

Comment: @ChantryCargill My focus is not on the theory behind Laplace and Fourier transforms but on how they can be used to find integrals.

Comment: You might also check out the [artofproblemsolving forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php). I'm sure they have tons of arguments using the methods you've mentioned.

Comment: @RobertCardona Yes, I know it, there's also the specialized forum http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/ , but the applications of the techniques I mentioned are very rare.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the *best* books to learn these stuff may be found in physics and engineering textbooks. Here are some reference books:

1. [*Introduction to Methods of Applied Mathematics or Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45901230/Sean-Mauch-Introduction-to-Methods-of-Applied-Mathematics#scribd) by Sean Mauch
2. [*Mathematical Methods for Physicists: A Concise Introduction*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521655447) by Tai L. Chow
3. [*Mathematics for Electrical Engineering and Computing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/075065855X) by Mary P Attenborough
4. [*Mathematics for Physics I*](http://www.goldbart.gatech.edu/PG_MS_MfP.htm) by Michael Stone and Paul Goldbart
5. [*Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471198269) by Mary L. Boas

My most personal recommendation book to learn these three subjects is book number 5. In addition, you might find these old books interesting to learn (although, these books don't discuss those subjects specifically): *A Treatise on Integral Calculus [Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr01edwauoft)* and *[Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonintegr02edwauoft)* by  Joseph Edwards. Well, I hope all these books can help you.

Comment: I've given you the bounty since it would have been gone, anyway the question is still unanswered but thanks for the references, I didn't know them : )

Comment: @user153330 Thank you but what kind of answer do you want? I'll add some details to my answer.